# Uso da biblioteca pthread em ambiente windows

Tags: c, biblioteca

É possível trabalhar com a biblioteca pthread normalmente em um ambiente windows? Ou deve ser apenas em linux?

Answer (score 5):

Como se diz [aqui](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library), que acho uma afirmação muito correta para o esclarecimento desta dúvida:

> Pthreads é parte do *POSIX* e *Windows* não é um sistema *POSIX*.

De qualquer modo existe apenas uma implementação da `pthread.h` para Windows chamada [`pthreads-win32`](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), mas não possui todas as funções originais. [Aqui](https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/conformance.html) pode ver a conformidade com a biblioteca original. Pode-a usar com MinGW ou TDM-GCC.

Comment: Legal saber que existe uma biblioteca de compatibilidade. Lembrando que nem mesmo quando o Windows implementava uma API POSIX (até o NT 4), não havia pthreads nela.

Comment: Talvez fosse legal adicionar a recomendação de usar uma biblioteca que abstraia threads nos dois sistemas. Tem vários projetos que rodam em Windows e UNIX, então imagino que deva haver um bom número de abstraçôes de threads para facilitar isto. Tipo: TinyCThread (https://tinycthread.github.io/).

Answer (score -5):

É possível sim, basta utilizar o wsl 2, que simula um sistema linux dentro do linux.
Outra forma, que também usa a primeira é através de containers (dockers).
O Visual Studio Code oferece suporte para todas essas ferramentas.
Existem vídeos no Youtube sobre tudo isso!!!